# Actionscript 2 giving strange results

Tags: flash, actionscript, decimal, multiplication

Input variable is k (testing 1, 10, 100, 1000 etc), dp = .00 to .0000000 (2 to 7 decimal places),
k19 is the result. Actionscript 2, (all inside a mc, simple conversion inch to mm).

```
k19 = k * 25.4; trace(k19); 
k19 = int(k19*dp)/dp; trace(k19);
```

The first trace is always correct answer, second trace shows wrong results the more zeros are added. Have tried using these inputs:

```
k is 10, dp is .00, k19 shows 25.4, 
k is 100, dp is .0000, k19 shows 2540, 
k is 100, dp is .00000, k19 shows -17549.67296, 
k is 1000, dp is .00000, k19 shows -17549.67296, 
k is 10000; dp is .00000, k19 shows -3698.03776, 
k is 100000, dp is .00000, k19 shows 5969.29536, 
k is 10, dp is .0000000, k19 shows -175.4967296.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.00` and `.00000` should be the same number, zero. Multiplying by zero should be zero. Dividing zero by zero is an illegal operation, and should result in `NaN`. I don't quite know ActionScript, but I'm more surprised you're getting _any_ results. Are you trying to round to certain number of decimals? if so, `dp` should be `100` or `100000`, not `.00` or `.00000`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, dp actually is 100, 1000 etc, the .00, .000 is what I make visible on screen only. So the code works, except for the strange results.

Comment: Same question without variables. All code is on a button: on(release){
 result = 10000 * 1.23456789; //trace is 12345.6789 correct;
 result = int(result * 100000)/100000; //trace is 12345.6789;
//same calculation in a different way:
 result1 = int(10000 * 1.23456789 * 100000)/100000; //trace is 12345.6789
//more decimal places
 result2 = int(10000 * 1.23456789 * 1000000)/1000000; //trace is -5392.22989 wrong;
 result3 = int(10000 * 1.23456789 * 10000000)/10000000; //trace is -109.7262585; 
 result4 = int(10000 * 1.0 * 10000000)/10000000; //trace is 121.5752192
 }

Comment: I've tried the same code on another PC and get same results.

Comment: Replaced all 'int' with 'Math.floor' or 'Math.ceil' and all is well.

Comment: I don't know what you did, and I don't know what `trace` is, but `int(10000 * 1.23456789 * 1000000)/1000000` evaluates to `12345.678899`, not `-5392.22989`. No idea where that result came from. Can you post [example]?

Comment: trace(variable) just shows the results. I had been using 'int' for years and never came across such errors. This code is on a button and just a stop() in the action frame, nothing else. My result for the following is: 121.5752192: on(release){
result = int(10000 * 1 * 10000000)/10000000
}

Comment: @user20220056 Use **Number** instead of using **Int** when dealing with fractions...

Comment: I know how to avoid strange results, best not using int() at all. I discovered that the calculation itself is irrelevant.  Only if int() has to deal with 10 billion or more will all results go crazy.  A 1 with 10 zeros will cause errors every time, so will any number with 11 digits left of the decimal point. Any value lower than that works fine.

Comment: Please see video regarding this issue:  [youtube link] (https://youtu.be/lRyjeoZppu4)